# How to use Monotype Corsiva font in c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I am facing problem with font class when i am using "Monotype Corsiva" font family.Below in my c# code

```
Font drawFont = new Font("Monotype Corsiva", 14);

exception generating "Font 'Monotype Corsiva' does not support style 'Regular'."
```

Comment: is this font installed your pc?

Comment: yes, i checked this by using  InstalledFontCollection ifc =new InstalledFontCollection();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This font may only have Italic variants. Try setting the font style to Italic. But keep in mind that when you reference fonts by name, it will only show up correctly on client PCs if they have the same font installed.

Comment: Complementing @Mike Strobel's answer, you may programatically install fonts:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14796162/how-to-install-a-windows-font-using-c-sharp