# How to install a Font programmatically (C#)

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, fonts

is there a way to permanently add a Font to a Windows 7/8 PC programmatically?
I have read several posts about the AddFontResource DLL-Import, but it doesn't seem to work.

Besides of that, the [MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183326%28VS.85%29.aspx) says the font will be deleted after a restart of the computer, unless the font is added into the registry.

How can I install a font permanently? How can I add the font to the registry? Is it always the same name/entry?

I have to add the font dynamically on runtime, because I get the font as soon as the user selects it.

**Remark**: I know how to add a registry entry. My question is more about the compatibility between Windows XP, Vista, 7 and 8 and the different font-types. Maybe there is a way to start an other exe which installs the font for me.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14796162/how-to-install-a-windows-font-using-c-sharp

Comment: As I pointed out I read several of those posts, but they dont answer my question. I want the font to be installed permanently and I asked something about the registry also.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As you mentioned, you can launch other executables to install TrueType Fonts for you. I don't know your specific use cases but I'll run down the methods I know of and maybe one will be of use to you.

Windows has a built-in utility called **fontview.exe**, which you can invoke simply by calling `Process.Start("Path\to\file.ttf")` on any valid TrueType Font... assuming default file associations. This is akin to launching it manually from Windows Explorer. The advantage here is it's really trivial, but it still requires user interaction per font to install. As far as I know there is no way to invoke the "Install" portion of this process as an argument, but even if there was you'd still have to elevate permissions and battle UAC.

The more intriguing option is a utility called [FontReg](http://code.kliu.org/misc/fontreg/) that replaces the deprecated fontinst.exe that was included on older versions of Windows. **FontReg** enables you to programatically install an entire directory of Fonts by invoking the executable with the **/copy** switch:

```
    var info = new ProcessStartInfo()
        {
            FileName = "Path\to\FontReg.exe",
            Arguments = "/copy",
            UseShellExecute = false,
            WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden

        };

   Process.Start(info);
```

Note that the Fonts have to be in the root of wherever **FontReg.exe** is located. You'll also have to have administrator privileges. If you need your Font installations to be completely transparent, I would suggest launching your application with elevated permissions and approve of the UAC up front, that way when you spawn your child processes you wont need user approval [Permissions stuff](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2532769/how-to-start-a-process-as-administrator-mode-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Yes, I already startup with elevated permissions so that should be no problem. I will inform myself about the two methods you wrote down. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Ok, I decided I will do it with the FontReg.exe. It looks like it's the best way to install the font. Thanks for the support!

Comment: @ElMac No problem. I believe the source is bundled with the rest of the distributables so you can peek and see how it was done if you're so inclined. I've only skimmed the logic but it looks to be on the same logic path: copy then register.

Comment: I found that tool too and plan on using it.  One quick note though, the readme that ships with the tool specifically says it's not the folder containing FontReg.exe but the CURRENT folder - which may not be the same.      EG, you're in a command prompt, in folder c:\fonts, and run c:\myTools\fontreg.exe, that'll look for fonts in c:\fonts rather than fonts in c:\myTools.

Answer (score 14):

I've been having the same issue for the past few days and each solution I found was producing different problems.

I managed to come up with a working code with my colleague and I thought I'd share it for everyone. The code can be found in the following pastebin link:

[Installing a font programatically in C#](http://pastebin.com/C99TmXBn)

**EDIT**
In the event this code becomes irretrievable in the future, I have copied it directly into the answer.

```
[DllImport("gdi32", EntryPoint = "AddFontResource")]
public static extern int AddFontResourceA(string lpFileName);
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
private static extern int AddFontResource(string lpszFilename);
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
private static extern int CreateScalableFontResource(uint fdwHidden, string
    lpszFontRes, string lpszFontFile, string lpszCurrentPath);

/// <summary>
/// Installs font on the user's system and adds it to the registry so it's available on the next session
/// Your font must be included in your project with its build path set to 'Content' and its Copy property
/// set to 'Copy Always'
/// </summary>
/// <param name="contentFontName">Your font to be passed as a resource (i.e. "myfont.tff")</param>
private static void RegisterFont(string contentFontName)
{
    // Creates the full path where your font will be installed
    var fontDestination = Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Fonts), contentFontName);

    if (!File.Exists(fontDestination))
    {
        // Copies font to destination
        System.IO.File.Copy(Path.Combine(System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), contentFontName), fontDestination);

        // Retrieves font name
        // Makes sure you reference System.Drawing
        PrivateFontCollection fontCol = new PrivateFontCollection();
        fontCol.AddFontFile(fontDestination);
        var actualFontName = fontCol.Families[0].Name;

        //Add font
        AddFontResource(fontDestination);
        //Add registry entry   
        Registry.SetValue(@"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Fonts",actualFontName, contentFontName, RegistryValueKind.String);
    }
}
```

Comment: necessary `namespaces`:
 `using Microsoft.Win32; using System.Drawing.Text; using System.IO; using System.Runtime.InteropServices;`

Comment: I'll document this here in case someone else stumbles upon the same problem: I needed to install the font for the current user only. To achieve that, I changed `fontDestination` to `Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), "Microsoft", "Windows", "Fonts", contentFontName)` and the Registry keyName to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Fonts`

Answer (score 2):

According to docs of [AddFontResource()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183326(v=vs.85).aspx)

> This function installs the font only for the current session. When the
>   system restarts, the font will not be present. To have the font
>   installed even after restarting the system, the font must be listed in
>   the registry.

So the best option i found is to copy the font to windows font directory

```
File.Copy("MyNewFont.ttf",
    Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(SpecialFolder.Windows),
        "Fonts", "MyNewFont.ttf"));
```

And then add respective entries in registery,Like

```
Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey key = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Fonts");
                    key.SetValue("My Font Description", "fontname.tff");
                    key.Close();
```

Comment: ex = {"Access to the path 'C:\Windows\Fonts\fontname.otf' is denied."}. Tested under windows 10

Comment: Edit, sorry thought I was running as admin. Does appear to work if admin but the font doesn't actually install

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Answer (score 2):

Building on Erik Bongers answer that has the nice properties of working without reboot and showing a "Installing font..." dialogbox which disappears by itself, but which does not seem to work for Windows 8+

```
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace YourApp.Common
{
    public static class FontHandling
    {
        public static bool IsFontInstalled(string fontName)
        {
            using (var testFont = new System.Drawing.Font(fontName, 8))
                return 0 == string.Compare(fontName, testFont.Name, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
        }

        public static void InstallFont(string fontSourcePath)
        {
            var shellAppType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Shell.Application");
            var shell = Activator.CreateInstance(shellAppType);
            var fontFolder = (Shell32.Folder)shellAppType.InvokeMember("NameSpace", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, shell, new object[] { Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Fonts) });
            if (File.Exists(fontSourcePath))
                fontFolder.CopyHere(fontSourcePath);
        }
    }
}
```

The required shell32.dll should not be directly referenced from the system32 folder. Instead go to "AddReferences --> COM" and there search for "Microsoft Shell Controls And Automation" and reference this.

Finally if you want to ensure the existence of a custom font for your program, you can add the font to the source code (eg. in a separate Fonts folder) and setting its properties: Build Action: None, Copy to Output Directory: Copy if newer.

Comment: Happy to see this is a living question and people are keeping the answers up to date 

Answer (score 2):

In my example below, in order for the code to work, place your fonts in the Fonts folder in the exe root.

Also the font name should be of similar format **OpenSans-Regular.ttf**, where the first part is the name before the dash, and the second part is the style.

I tested the fonts on google fonts, it didn't cause any problems, but there may be fonts with terrible names.

```
using Microsoft.Win32;
using System;
using System.Drawing.Text;
using System.IO;

    private string GetFontName(string fontPath)
    {
        PrivateFontCollection fontCol = new PrivateFontCollection();
        fontCol.AddFontFile(fontPath);
        return fontCol.Families[0].Name;
    }
    public void InstallFonts()
    {
        // user fonts folder
        var fontsPath = $"{Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()}\\Fonts";

        // system fonts folder
        var fontDestination = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Fonts);

        // import fonts
        foreach (var fontFile in Directory.GetFiles(fontsPath))
        {
            // get font props
            var fontFileName = Path.GetFileName(fontFile);               // OpenSans-Regular.ttf
            var fontName = GetFontName(fontFile);                        // Open Sans
            var fontStyle = fontFileName.Split('-')[1].Split('.')[0];    // Regular, Bold 
            var fontType = fontFileName.Split('-')[1].Split('.')[1];     // ttf

            if (File.Exists($"{fontDestination}\\{fontFileName}"))
            {
                return;   
            }
            // copy font to dest
            File.Copy(Path.Combine(fontsPath, fontFileName), Path.Combine(fontDestination, fontFileName));

            // add to registry
            using (RegistryKey fontsKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Fonts", true))
            {
                fontsKey.SetValue(string.Format("{0} {1} {2}", fontName, fontStyle, fontType == "ttf" ? "(TrueType)" : "(OpenType)"),
                    fontFileName, RegistryValueKind.String);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

The best way to install a font without requiring admin-privileges would be to install it as a User Font.

```
public static void InstallFont(string FontName, string FullFontName, byte[] FontData)
{
    string localAppDataPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData);
    string windowsFontsPath = Path.Combine(localAppDataPath, "Microsoft", "Windows", "Fonts");
    string FontPath = Path.Combine(windowsFontsPath, $"{FontName}.ttf");

    File.WriteAllBytes(FontPath, FontData);

    RegistryKey fontKey = Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey(@"Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Fonts");
    fontKey.SetValue($"{FullFontName} (TrueType)", FontPath);
    fontKey.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
internal static void InstalarFuente(string NombreFnt,string RutaFnt)
{
    string CMD = string.Format("copy /Y \"{0}\" \"%WINDIR%\\Fonts\" ", RutaFnt);
    EjecutarCMD(CMD);

    System.IO.FileInfo FInfo = new System.IO.FileInfo(RutaFnt);
    CMD = string.Format("reg add \"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows NT\\CurrentVersion\\Fonts\" /v \"{0}\" /t REG_SZ /d {1} /f", NombreFnt, FInfo.Name);
    EjecutarCMD(CMD);
}

public static void EjecutarCMD(string Comando)
{
    System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo Info = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe");
    Info.Arguments = string.Format("/c {0}", Comando);
    Info.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(Info);
}
```

Logoff to take into account the Font.

Comment: that looks incredibly dangerous - what if the font file already exists but contains a different font?

Answer (score 0):

This solution is clean, works *without reboot*(!) but it does show a "Installing font..." dialogbox (which disappears by itself).

First, add a reference to system32\shell32.dll in your project.
And then, use just these 3 lines of code to install a font:

```
Shell32.Shell shell = new Shell32.Shell();
Shell32.Folder fontFolder = shell.NameSpace(0x14);
fontFolder.CopyHere(@"path_to\the_font.ttf");
```

3 lines of code :)

Comment: whats that `path_to` mean?

Answer (score 0):

If you have Visual Studio 2017, you can create a new Visual Studio Installer - Setup Project.  You can edit the installer to remove dialog boxes, only leaving the Finish dialog to show the user that it ran OK.

From the File System on Target Machine (in the Visual Studio project), add the special directory called Fonts.  Then add all the fonts you want into the Fonts directory.  If you look at the Properties of each font you add, you will see that Visual Studio has already assumed you want to register each font.

Compile the project, and you have an MSI with a setup.exe that you can deploy.  Of course, you need to run it as an administrator, but other than that, this little program works fast and efficiently.  I found that this was the easiest way to install fonts on Windows.

Comment: I did this as a standalone project for existing customers - we had a need for a quick way to get a font out.  For new customers, I added this technique into its installer project (I already had a VS Setup project for that application), so it worked out great.  Twice.

Answer (score 0):

Create 2 new folders in the project named *InstallFonts* and *Helpers*.

In the folder *Helpers*, create a new class file Fonts.cs and copy the following code into it:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace myFirstAzureWebApp.Helpers
{
    public class Fonts
    {
        [DllImport("gdi32", EntryPoint = "AddFontResource")]
        public static extern int AddFontResourceA(string lpFileName);
        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
        public static extern int AddFontResource(string lpszFilename);
    }
}
```

Copy required fonts from your local font folder (C:\Windows\Fonts) to the *InstallFonts* folder. For testing, copy only a handful of fonts to safe space. Set the properties Build Action to Content and Copy to Output Directory to Copy Always

Find the file Global.asax in the project's root folder and replace it with this code:

```
using myFirstAzureWebApp.Helpers;
using System.IO;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Optimization;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace myTextControlAzureApp
{
    public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            foreach (string font in Directory.GetFiles(
                Path.Combine(HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath, "InstallFonts")))
            {
                Fonts.AddFontResource(font);
            }

            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        }
    }
}
```