# include fonts in c# application form after publishing

Tags: c#, windows-forms-core

**i have created a project and publish it using fonts loading on my windows which i have installed on my windows .... it's working on my pc
but when i open the published application on other devices its not showing the fonts . how can include those fonts on the project than publish it so when i install the application on other devices i can see fonts desgin  **

how can i add those fonts on the project so the application loading fonts from project not on my windows fonts

** i have tried some codes but it's not working at all   **

Comment: Please post the code you have tried.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install a Font programmatically (C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21986744/how-to-install-a-font-programmatically-c)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the font file into the project and copy the file to the output directory on every build.

[image]

Then load the font from the same directory as your application via a relative path.

```cs
    var fontCollection = new PrivateFontCollection();

    fontCollection.AddFontFile("myFontFile.otf");

    label.Font = new Font(fontCollection.Families[0], 40);
```

[image]

Comment: Thank u but where do i write this code ?

Comment: Anywhere you want. Youre changing the font. You can do it on a button click, you can do it on application startup.

Comment: thanks , it works ! how can i used two fonts ? label1 font a label2 font b