# WPF Fonts Registering to Windows

Tags: c#, wpf, fonts

To register my custom fonts to windows, i am creating one .reg file and adding it to my WPF installer. Everything works fien and the fonts gets installed. However when I uninstall the application, those fonts also gets uninstalled and some random fonts gets applied to the system. Actually, the  whole Windows behave differently( i am guessing something wrong happens with the registry file). How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: Are you trying to install fonts to the operating system, or just trying to use them in a WPF Application?

Comment: I am installing it to the operating system.Don't know why but its a business requirement.

Comment: Have you seen the answer to the [How to install a windows font using C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14796162/how-to-install-a-windows-font-using-c-sharp) question?

Comment: I have followed this approach to install the fonts:http://egilhansen.com/2010/09/29/how-package-fonts-msi-file-easy-deployment    I create the .reg file using the same approach and then I import it in my setup project that i create using InstallShield in my VS2013. Fonts are getiing installed and its working fine. Problem occurs when I uninstall the application

Comment: Are you sure that you haven't got the Font uninstall as part of the uninstall process of your application?

Comment: yeah fonts are getting uninstalled (I've mentioned this in the question). What should I do so that the fonts don't get uninstalled

Comment: I'm not asking if your Fonts are getting uninstalled... that much is clear. I was asking if *your Setup Project has been set up to uninstall the fonts*... eg. Look in your setup project uninstallation section.