# Does a client needs a font to see a PDF document generated on the server?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, architecture, fonts, client-server, webfonts

A client/server architecture generates in the server a document with a specific font.
Does need the client to install the same font to see the document?

The document can be accessed through a desktop client application and web browsers(cient)

Comment: yes:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/107936/how-to-add-some-non-standard-font-to-a-website
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14796162/how-to-install-a-windows-font-using-c-sharp

Comment: @RobConklin I do not need the way of use a font in my application, this is a general question, in particular I want to know if I'm a client of a website I am not so sure that I need to install a particular font to see the website, I am asking if this is the same when I download a document from a website and I do not have installed the fonts

Comment: What kind of "document" are we talking here?  Are you talking a Word document?  Or a HTML Document?  Or a PDF document?  These all have different solution spaces.  Word & PDF have methods to embed fonts in the document itself.  HTML needs to use the method above to download the font for that rendering.

Comment: @RobConklin Sorry for not being specific. It is a pdf document.

Comment: http://www.prepressure.com/pdf/basics/fonts  The actual mechanics of getting the fonts embedded will vary based on what tools/libraries you are using.

Comment: @RobConklin Thanks, pdf can embed fonts and they will have a bigger size than normally pdf. So, the client don´t need to install the same font as the server to see the document correctly