# set font .ttf to C# winform application

Tags: c#

I have font (.ttf) install to my computer,but when I release my application to another computer the font change. How can I force font not to change?

note: I can't download TFConvert because i have visual studio 2015 not 2010

Comment: I think this is because these fonts are not present in deployed machine you need to copy these font there.

Comment: they have the font,i have read on https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc533017.aspx I have to add my font to my application i add .ttf but it didn't work

Comment: If the font is present on the machine where you deploy, you should be able to use it. If it's not present you need to create a .tinyfont. Here is a tool that is able to do that: http://informatix.miloush.net/microframework/Utilities/TinyFontTool.aspx. Disclaimer: I haven't used it myself.

Comment: `YourApp.Properties.Settings.Default.UserFont = new Font(<your_font>, 24, FontStyle.Bold);` ?

Comment: Possible related: [How to install a windows font using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14796162/4519059) ;).